# A few questions on the later chapters in Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Walter Rudin (3rd Edition)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am currently reading *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin (3rd Edition). I am enjoying the book and it's terseness, which isn't an issue for me. What I do have a problem with is that I hear the later chapters (chapters 9-11 specifically) aren't very good. I have a couple of questions.

1)What precisely makes these chapters subpar? Is it still worth reading, but adding in some supplements?

2)I plan on reading *Real and Complex Analysis* by Walter Rudin after this book, does it fill in the supposed missing quality of the last few chapters? Like, I know Lebesgue Theory and the Lebesgue Integral are important and that apparently isn't treated nicely in *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* (it would be nice if you could tell me exactly why this is so) either, but is it developed better in *Real and Complex Analysis*?

Thanks in advance for any response.

Comment: I found Real and Complex Analysis to be a big jump from baby Rudin so I read Folland's Real Analysis first.

Comment: It would help to remind us what those chapters cover. I remember personally disliking his coverage of differential forms and Stokes. I hadn't taken any several variables classes, so I had no idea what was going on other than pure abstract nonsense.

Comment: Aren't differential forms, tensors and the like pretty much abstract nonsense anyway?

Comment: Rudin's chapter on differential forms is amost pure formalism, with no grounding in "reality" ar all. On the other hand, the chapter on Lebesgue Integration is a nicely done short intro to the subject.

Comment: @Chilango "Rudin's chapter on differential forms is amost pure formalism, with no grounding in 'reality' at all." What precisely do you mean by that?

Comment: @Sr.Vishi: Well, compare his treatment with Weintraub's Differential Forms to see the difference.